# Can I use my existing git repo with openshift?

Tags: git, openshift

Is it necessary to have git repo on openshift only? I already have bitbucket / github git repo and would prefer to push there only. Can I simply hook into it so that openshift gets intimation ?

Or for simplification, I push only at github, but when I want to deploy, I do something with openshift?

I did check [this](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/kb/kb-e1006-sync-new-git-repo-with-your-own-existing-git-repo) but it confused me:  it's talking about merging exiting and new (openshift) git ?

Comment: Could you proofread the question?  It's very hard to understand.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

I have the impression that you're not used to use git enough yet. I'd advise you to get into git to fully understand how to push your code to openshift. Nevertheless let me try to explain you the steps involved:
As you'd do with git in general, the approach to choose here is to clone your other git repo (ex. on bitbucket) to your local machine:

`git clone <bitbucket-repo-url>`

Your local clone has then your other repo (bitbucket etc.) as remote repo. Your remote repo is stored with the alias "origin" (the default alias used by git if you clone). You then add the openshift repo as remote to your clone. You do that while explicitly using an alias for the remote repo you add - I'm using "openshift" as alias here:

`git remote add openshift -f <openshift-git-repo-url>`

In order to then be able to push the code from your local git repo to openshift you first have to merge your openshift repo with your local bitbucket clone. You do that by issuing locally:

`git merge openshift/master -s recursive -X ours`

With this command you tell git to merge the master branch in the openshift git repo with your local git repo. You tell it to merge using the recursive merging strategy and to choose your ("ours") version when there are conflicts.

Once the merge is executed you're ready to push your git repo to openshift. You do that by doing:

`git push openshift HEAD`

You tell git to push your local code to the HEAD branch on the remote repo called "openshift" (the alias we stored the openshift git repo at, some paragraphs further up).

btw. I wrote a jboss tools blog which was demonstrating how to use the openshift-java-client some months ago: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Enable-openshift-ciFullExampleUsingOpenshift-java-client . You'll spot the above steps in the last paragraph "We're almost there".

Comment: I think this still does not answer the question. The question is about not using openshift's git repo as the remote, but instead using the repo on github (or bitbucket for that matter) as the git repo. A push to github repo used for collaborating should also ensure that it gets reflected in openshift. I'm also looking for the same but have not find the answer. I'll try to update if I get a solution for this

Comment: You cannot not use the openshift git repo. The git repo within OpenShift is how you hand OpenShift your code over. There's no alternative, there's no "use github instead". As I tried to outline above, the git repo on OpenShift is not excluding you from using github. If you use github/bitbucket/XX as your master source control repo - and most users will do that - , then you would simply add the OpenShift git repo as remote to your local github/bitbucket/XX-clone. Pushing to OpenShift is then equivalent to deplyoing to OpenShift.

Comment: I´m not familiar with git, only SVN/CVS but, my doubt is about number of users in git repo. How many users openshift support?

Comment: @Ricardo AFAIK there's no explicit limit communicated. You can add access by adding more public keys in the settings tab (or using rhc). However, the OpenShift GIT repo is NOT really intended to be used as a development repository. Keep in mind that pushing to the OpenShift GIT repo _IS_ deploying your application, so every change pushed updates the application.

Comment: If I understand it, if I work with openshift I should work with a development repo (for example github) and if I want to deploy it just push on openshift HEAD, riht?

Comment: There's no "should". You can apply whatever strategy fits best for you. The simplest approach is to host your code in the OpenShift git repo only. On the other hand OpenShift is lacking what classic code repositories like github offer: you have no code browser, pull-requests etc. Thus I tend to think that having your code hosted on github (or any other public git repo) and pushing to the OpenShift git repo to deploy it - as outlined above - is a pretty genuine approach. Of course you can go for even more complex setups if there are benefits for you.

Comment: Worth noting that the -f flag, and the ssh part of the git URL are both essential

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, it is something Github collaborate with AppHarbor which you can use github as development repo while AppHarbor as the deployment repo and you only maintain the source at 1 side instead of bother other. So the principle very straight forward and programmer want to have better live, push code to github then github hook up OpenShift do the deployment which exactly the same source from github instead of repeatly pushing twice the same source to two servers and github can provide better issue maintenance than openshift that's why Im looking this approach too.

Comment: Is there any way I can have openshift/master track origin/develop? I want my development (staging) code to be on openshift to act as a staging server.

Comment: @adietisheim with the new git 2.9 you will need to add `--allow-unrelated-histories` as git default has changed to not allow merging unrelated histories.

Comment: @adietisheim please correct your answer mentionint `--allow-unrelated-histories`; it is needed as of git 2.9: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.9.0.txt#L58-L68

Comment: I doesn't seem to be able to SSH to openshift as openshift doesn't seem to support port forwarding for SSH port 22 into pods, only forwarding of 80 and 443 port

Answer (score 23):

I know the question is 2-year old and the [@adietisheim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12669112/1179841) has been accepted. I personally don't like to merge the openshift repo into my local clone because I don't want to mix the OpenShift repo into the master branch of my public repo.

Assuming you have added the remote using `git remote add openshift <openshift-git-repo-url>`, here is what I would do:

Create a new local branch `openshift` based on the `master` branch.

```
git checkout -b openshift
```

You could make some commits on the branch `openshift` such as your app deployment configurations.
Then, push the current branch to the remote ref matching master in the OpenShift repository with the flag `-f` to overwrite everything in the remote `master` branch.

```
git push openshift master -f
```

Whenever I want to deploy my app to OpenShift, I would check out the local `openshift` branch and merge `master` branch with it, then force push to OpenShift, however `-f` may not be required for the next pushes:

```
git checkout openshift
git merge --no-ff master
git push openshift master -f
```

Answer (score 6):

From you project folder, do

```
git remote add backup user@server:/path/to/git/test.git
git push backup master
```

You can read [Pushing to two git remote origins from one repository](http://www.hostatic.ro/2011/09/29/pushing-to-two-git-remote-origins-from-one-repository/) and [Changing git remote origin](http://andersonleeb.com/blog/changing-git-remote-origin).

Comment: `git push backup master` is sufficient, you don't need to specify both sides of the refspec.

Comment: The tip to push to 2 git remote is perfect. You can also then do a: `git push -u all` to 'all' to the default remote. When doing `git push`, it will the subsequently push to the 2 repos !

Answer (score 5):

I agree with @adietisheim's answer: you need to understand better git before deploying with openshift =)

Now, even if you understand git, it is not necessarily obvious how to deploy your existing repo if your directory structure does not match the directory structure required by openshift, and if you want to keep your old directory structure.

For that, I have the following tips:

- separate options that are deployment dependent from those that are not into different files. For example, I separate my database settings from other settings into different files as:

  - settings_deploy/openshift
  - settings_deploy/localhost

  and then symlink to your localhost test as something like:

  ```
  ln -s settings_deploy/localhost settings_deploy_file
  ```

  Another option is to detect the host by using environment variables:

  ```
  if 'OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME' in os.environ:
      //openshift configurations
  else:
      //localhost
  ```

  This is a bit simpler since it allows you to put all the configs on a single file. It is a bit less general, since if ever another one of your hosts offers an `OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME` environment variable (unlikely for this one) the method breaks. Anyways, you still have to clearly separate what is deployment dependent and what is not.
- create a local deploy directory
- clone the initial openshift template into it
- create a deploy script that:

  - hardlinks everything from your old existing local to their correct locations at the

    hardlinks are fast to create and use very little memory

    you could use something like:

    `cp -lrf original_repo_dir  deploy_repo_dir`
  - keep only the correct `settings_deploy` file in the deploy repo:

    `cd deploy_repo`

    `mv settings_deploy/openshift settings_deploy_file`

    `rm -r settings_deploy`
  - force push:

    `cd deploy_repo`

    `git push -f origin master`
  - clean the deploy repo:

    `git reset --hard HEAD`

    `git clean -df`

for those interested in django deployment, I have an example on [my github](https://github.com/cirosantilli/django-cheat/tree/783c803d3334097dc0a59439bee024b8d8490265), in particular check out the `deploy.sh` script and the project `projects/elearn` which it deploys.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to pass in an existing Git repository into the asset pipeline via

```
rhc create-app $APPNAME ruby-1.9 --from-code $GIT_LOCATION
```

The remote Git repository then delivers the initial application for OpenShift.

As a second possibility, you can skip the creation of the local OpenSHift Git repository via

```
rhc create-app $APPNAME ruby-1.9 --no-git
```

and then use the steps described above to merge the OpenShift remote Git repository into your local Git repository.

Answer (score 4):

Mohannd's answer is perfect, but I would like to sum up the complete solution, in case some else needs it:

To use your github repo as an Openshift repo, there is no perfect solution now, because, Openshfit uses git hooks to trigger the deployment or redeployment based on your commits. However, the smartest way would be to use 2 repos (the openshift's one and your github's one) to push simultaneously the code to.

To do this:
Add a remote named "all" and add 2 push urls to it.

```
git remote add all ssh://23456781234567@yourapp-namespace.rhcloud.com/~/git/yourapp.git
git remote set-url openshift-git-repo --push --add ssh://23456781234567@yourapp-namespace.rhcloud.com/~/git/yourapp.git
git remote set-url github-repo --push --add git@github.com:youruser/yourapp.git
```

Then set the remote named 'all' as the default push remote:

```
git push -u all
```

To commit and push your code, proceed as usual: It will push on the 2 remotes and deploy on OpenShift

```
git add .
git commit -m "my commit"
git push
```

And watch the result:

```
[master 3fc96b2] my commit
 1 file changed, 2 deletions(-)
MyLaptop:myapp User$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 291 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:User/myapp.git
   a036a44..3fc96b2  master -> master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 291 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Stopping PHP 5.4 cartridge (Apache+mod_php)
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Waiting for stop to finish
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit 3fc96b2
remote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 9037d37a
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting PHP 5.4 cartridge (Apache+mod_php)
remote: Application directory "/" selected as DocumentRoot
remote: -------------------------
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success
To ssh://23456789@myapp-namespace.rhcloud.com/~/git/myapp.git/
   a036a44..3fc96b2  master -> master
MyLaptop:myapp User$
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You have an error. You can have multiple repositories, but they both can't be named "origin". They must be unique, like: **origin** and **origin2**

Comment: using this implementation but i got an error that says No such remote 'openshift-git-repo' .. i think there is a missing on the script above..

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do what you want, i.e. skip Openshift's repo.
What you need to do is set up a jenkins, and have it poll your own repository.

There's a link here that explains how to set it up from scratch:
http://blog.anthavio.net/2014/01/deploy-to-openshift-from-github.html

Answer (score 1):

I ran into problems deploying a pre-existing code repository to Openshift. In my particular context, where I tried to deploy a tomcat webapp, the Openshift tomcat configuration files included in the .openshift folder were crucial.

What fixed it for me was the inclusion of the .openshift folder in my existing source tree, as well as the inclusion of the openshift profile in my maven pom.xml file.

This is highly likely the same that would happen by merging your repository with the new openshift upstream one. For me, this is the "why" behind following sentence in adietisheim's great answer:

"In order to then be able to push the code from your local git repo to openshift you first have to merge your openshift repo with your local bitbucket clone."

In my case, this merge was needed to get the config files from the .openshift directory. It took a long time to figure out for me because pushing without the .openshift directory still made my app build and deploy successfully. The only behaviour I saw was a report on missing jsp files, which made me think that the problem was related to my own web.xml and servlet configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using github you can configure travis to made the deployment each time you made a change in your github repository

http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/openshift/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java then there's is an alternative approach. But even in this approach you would still use the OpenShift git repository. The git repository provided by OpenShift is how you give OpenShift your code, your deployable(s):

You can - instead of committing your code to the OpenShift git repo - simply give it your war-file. You clone the OpenShift git repo to your local machine. You then build a war from your application source and put this war into the deployments folder within your OpenShift git repo (clone). You then add, commit and push your local clone to OpenShift. Once the push executed successfully, the JBoss AS7 will pick your war and deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

TAKE EASY!

step 1: Create app. With your favorite method (from gitRepository, pre-maker Openshift, etc). if you use console metod 
step 2: `rhc git-clone nameApp`  
step 3: `rhc app-configure nameApp --auto-deploy` 
step 4: ENJOY!

Comment: That's fine, but that was just not the answer to the question :)