# how to push my github repo into openshift and make it to work

Tags: git, github, sftp, openshift

i'm newbie to openshift and git.I've my repo on github(https://github.com/punith21/vturesults)
how to push to my openshift and make it to work as my website

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use my existing git repo with openshift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657168/can-i-use-my-existing-git-repo-with-openshift)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer for this very similar question:  ([Can I use my existing git repo with openshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657168/can-i-use-my-existing-git-repo-with-openshift)).  You also need to make sure that your website is setup to be run on openshift correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your project should *"just work"*, as long as your source has been adapted to:

1. Take advantage of your project's [`package.json` file to document your server init process](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps#package_json)
2. [Check the system environment for runtime configuration details from OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/run-your-nodejs-projects-on-openshift-in-two-simple-steps#env_vars)

Once those two steps are completed you should be able to [launch your app using OpenShift's web workflow](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/launching-applications-with-openshifts-web-based-workflow), or by using the [`rhc` command-line tool](https://www.openshift.com/get-started#cli).