# Which is the root directory to deploy the files in openshift for PHP?

Tags: openshift

I have a PHP application with MySQL, which is the root directory to deploy the files ($ git clone "git_url" "directory_to_create")? Thanks. 
When I enter throw putty I see these directories:

app-deployments

app-root

git

mysql

php

Comment: ~/app-root/runtime/repo/

Comment: Thank you very much for the other answer. I have an issue I thought that by doing this line command ($ git clone ...github.com/username/simple.git ~/app-root/runtime/repo/) it will upload the files, however I see that it creates a new directory in the local-machine. Which command do I have to use to upload the files from a github url to my openshift instance?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657168/can-i-use-my-existing-git-repo-with-openshift

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It also possible to upload files throw FTP: https://forums.openshift.com/access-files-with-filezilla