# git clone : no address associated with name

Tags: git, github, ssh, openshift, git-clone

I know there are many question asked about this but i found them not working in my case

As I'm not very known to git I'm facing a problem cloning a repo from openshift server.
I have my ssh URL for my repo ( which is of the form ssh://some_text@my_site_url/~/git/my_app.git/ ), but when I'm trying to clone the repo using

```
git clone ssh://somt_text@my_site_url/~/git/my_app.git/
```

I'm getting this error message

> Cloning into 'my_app'...
>   ssh: Could not resolve hostname my_site_url: no address associated with name
>   
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I'm using git behind a proxy server of my college so I'm done setting the git proxy using

```
git config --global http.proxy httpProxy:port
git config --global https.proxy httpProxy:port
```

Please suggest if i'm missing any step or doing something wrong.

**Note:** I am using OpenShift to host my project and trying to access that using using ssh on my local computer.

Comment: I think he was having some problems with ssh, not with git proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing any step, but it seems that you are [using git behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server).

Just configure your proxy properly or even before that, make sure that your proxy provides you permission to use ssh (*if not you have to go for some other option to use https url anyhow*).

You can even try to use `github` in place of default `OpenShift` git repo (*as you mentioned in comment*), that will provide you with more options and of course more solutions in case you run into any porblem again.

See these for more help:

- [Can I use my existing git repo with openshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657168/can-i-use-my-existing-git-repo-with-openshift)
- [How-To: Keep a github repository and an OpenShift repository in sync](https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-keep-a-github-repository-and-an-openshift-repository-in-sync)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is enough if you use ssh

Absolute path:
git clone user@example.com:/home/my_user/git/my_app.git

Relative path:
git clone user@example.com:git/my_app.git

Comment: actually "somt_text@my_site_url/~/" this part or my ssh url i can't change as its given to me by openshift. Moreover if don't use that "ssh://" it gives fatal error saying repository does not exist. so what else can i do ?