# Pushes to Openshift project repo don't appear in private Gitlab repo

Tags: gitlab, openshift

I have searched for this a lot but I didn't find the solution I want.

I have one private repository on gitlab with flask microframework and I want to put that on openshift. I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12669112/5125212), then I changed the files structure to work good for openshift and everything was going good. But then I realized that any commit/push I do on openshift repo is not appearing on gitlab repo. Any solution? Or what is the useful workflow for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is because they are two different repository and you should push to both