# how should use source code of bitbucket repository for rhcloude?

Tags: openshift, bitbucket

This is the way,I have tried

[image]

I want to know, how to use bitbuket repository  use with openshift.

Comment: Is your repo public? What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenShift Online can't clone private repo in the first step of creating an app; the *"Source code repository could not be cloned"* error would be displayed.

This can be worked around by creating an empty OpenShift app and then pushing the private code into the OpenShift repo.

---

A few approaches on how to work with OpenShift repo as an additional remote to an existing repo are outlined [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657168/can-i-use-my-existing-git-repo-with-openshift/12669112).