# How to host openshift using repository url?

Tags: git, github, openshift, hosting, bitbucket

When hosting openshift, I met this error. I use github/bitbucket repository for the sources.

[image: view error image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in this way. 
You can clone bitbuket then add your remote branch with the openshift git repo.

follow this link.
[Use existing git repo with openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657168/can-i-use-my-existing-git-repo-with-openshift)

========================================================================

1) Clone your repo

```
$ git clone <bitbucket-repo-url>
```

2) Then, Add the remote origin for openshift

```
$ git remote add openshift -f <openshift-git-repo-url>
```

3) After that, Merge your openshift repo with your local bitbucket

```
$ git merge openshift/master
```

4) Finaly push your git repo to openshift

```
$ git push openshift HEAD
```

Happy coding...

Comment: Here I found another article belong to openshift and github

**[http://blog.anthavio.net/2014/01/deploy-to-openshift-from-github.html]**