# Openshift 3 SSH

Tags: ssh, openshift

In the OpenShift 2 I was able to just add my public key to the authorized keys set and do a simple ssh to my server. Now I am trying to migrate my app and just doing some test with simple deployment and ssh doesn't work. I would like to have ssh access to check what is wrong. But it seems ssh changed here - I cant find the info about where can I add a key or the info how to ssh (both of these infos were visible on OpenShift 2)

Is that possible or they closed possibility to do a simple ssh to them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `ssh`, you need to use the `oc rsh` command to connect to the pod running the application you want to access. You can also use a terminal in the web console by going to the pod for the application. Both provide an iteractive shell prompt. If want to execute a command only, you can also use `oc exec`.

Is there a specific task you are trying to do which you think requires `ssh` rather than `oc rsh` or `oc exec`?

Comment: Thank you. the build-in terminal was enough. now I found where my WAR's are compiled. According to my recent MVN profile it was copied to `/tmp/src/webapps`. Where should I copy it to deploy it on a Tomcat-like jboss server running on Openshift 3? PS. Just starting reading https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html found somewhere else here on stackoverflow! There is a chance that I will be on time with migration of my app (http://www.fridayweekend.com)! :)

Comment: How can I git push application by the mean of SSH when I don't have accessible SSH, only oc rsh? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12657168/can-i-use-my-existing-git-repo-with-openshift/12669112#12669112  I even tried to port forward 80 port whereas it works for apache, using same 80 port for ssh just doesn't work from outside (from inside it works)

Comment: @FantomX1 Create a separate question and explain your issue in detail in that. Don't ask questions as comments on other issues.